# how to draw inner or outer path for a path in svg

Tags: javascript, xpath, svg, path, svg-edit

I am new to svg , I need to draw a inner or outer path for the svg editor generated svg path , i am unable to draw . I tried a lot but i cant .

help me.

```
<path id="svg_1" d="m697.81641,349.89844l596,0l0,282l-596,0l0,-141l0,-141z" stroke-width="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#BBD1E8"/>
```

the previous line make a rect on svg editor . i need to draw a inner rect or outer rect for the above path . i need to make it like a compound wall . so i need to know is there any formula or calculation is there to do it dynamically . i tried this

```
<path d="M 0 0, 60 0, 60 60, 0 60 Z M 15 15, 15 45, 45 45, 45 15Z"/>
```

it working correctly but how can i make it dynamically for user generated path .

i tried for the following user generated code

```
<path id="svg_1" d="m1085,757.10199l309,-84.5l292,-2.5l243.5,256l-8.5,193.99799l-749,-62l-87,-147.99799l0,-153z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#BBD1E8"/>
```

i convert this as follows

```
<path id="svg_1" d="m1085,757.10199l309,-84.5l292,-2.5l243.5,256l-8.5,193.99799l-749,-62l-87,-147.99799l0,-153zm832.10199,1160l-9.5,234l-77.5,217l181,318.5l268.99799,66.5l13,-824l-222.99799,-162l-228,75z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#BBD1E8"/>
```

in this first m to z original path code second m to z is generated but not working

Comment: can you show ur current customized code...

Comment: my code is    <path id="svg_1" d="m697.81641,349.89844l596,0l0,282l-596,0l0,-141l0,-141z" stroke-width="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#BBD1E8"/>

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you are specifically trying to do (and why), as it may help with any suggested solutions.

Comment: @lan.. I update my question can you pls review it..